# apt --fix-broken install error sub-process

Tags: apt, kali-linux

After running `apt --fix-broken install`, I receive the following error:

```
 dpkg: error processing package qt4-designer (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qt4-designer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reinstalling the package:

```
 sudo apt-get --reinstall qt4-designer
```

If still issue persists,  delete all the files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` with the name qt4-designer*

Then install it again using `sudo apt-get install qt4-designer`